# C# - Math / Logic - Checking which Value is nearer

Tags: c#, math, logic, calculation

I know this looks like a lot of text but it might be actual fun for you to solve it :)?
See it as a *simple* math problem.

I struggle with my following logic, I have it in my head and want to start coding it but I don't know how and where to start. I have a Basic Idea and I will try to explain the whole thing as simple as possible but I need a lil help with how to code it. Maybe someone can show me how to code it or give me an improvement idear?

First of all I have a total of 8 doubles which serve as coordinates in my program.

2 of them are the static "main coordinates" which I want to test around. As an example:

```
double xmain = 110.0
double ymain = 120.0
```

I also have 2 more input double coordinates which change dynamically depending on what you type. for example:

```
double x = 80.0
double y = 90.0
```

now i want to compare double x with double xmain to see how close x is to xmain, the same with y and ymain.

For that I *could* do something like that:

```
double percentx = (x / xmain) * 100.0; // x is ~72% of xmain
double percenty = (y / ymain) * 100.0; // y is ~75% of ymain
```

but you have to assume too that the x value can be negative or higher as xmain so doing that wouldn't be a good idea as I get results like 140% or -50%. So is there another approach I could try?

Second thing I want to do is after comparing how close these two are to xmain and ymain compare if x and y are closer to xmain and ymain than the following doubles:

```
double nearestx = 85.0
double nearesty = 75.0
```

If the sum of x and y is closer to xmain and x is closer to ymain than nearestx and nearest y, then x and y should overwrite the values of nearestx and nearest y with their own values.

I tried something like that using the %calculation from earlier which I shouldn't use for that example but just to show you that I actually tried something here is my try:

```
combinedpercent = (percentx + percenty) / 2.0; //percent of new xy
nearestpercent = ((nearestx / xmain) * 100.0) + ((nearesty / xmain) * 100.0)) / 4.0; //percent of nearest xy

if (combinedpercent > nearestpercent) //if new xy is higher than nearest xy in percentage terms then true (you probably can code that better)
{
      nearestx = x;
      nearesty = y;
}
```

I know this approach is probably awful and it would be great if someone could point a different method how to compare results which value is more near than another (i need to do that with multiple values at the same time) instead of using percentages?

in a nutshell, i program a "bruteforce" coordinate system which has 2 fixed given x(main) and y(main) coordinates. now i get more random x and y coordinates as input which should be compared with the ones before and so on... i run the whole thing for a few minutes to get an output which was the closest to the input coordinates.

Thanks for anyones help :)

Comment: These are coordinates so you can just calculate the distance between the points using Pythagoras: `double dx = xmain - x; double dy = ymain - y; double delta = Math.Sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);`. Then just look for the lowest `delta`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you calculate the distance between two points ?

```
Math.Sqrt((xMain - x) * (xMain - x) + (yMain - y) * (yMain - y));
```

Comment: If only the nearest point is needed and not the exact distance, you could even remove the `Math.Sqrt`.

Comment: @KlausGütter Indeed !